# Angular (Click) not working on Chrome when using Select Option

Tags: angular, google-chrome, select

I created a dropdown list that worked perfectly on Firefox. I though my work was done when somebody tried it on Chrome.
For some reason the (click) function is never called

```
<select name="cars" id="car" title="cars" placeholder="select">
                        <option [value]="null" (click)="onCancelSelect(car);">Select</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let car of cars" (click)="onSelect(car);" [value]="car.id"> 
                            {{car.name}}
                        </option>
</select>
```

I did try to move the (click) function in the select tag. This time the function is called but car is "undefined".
What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `(change)` instead of `(click)` over the "select"

```
<select name="cars" id="car" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value);" title="cars" placeholder="select">
    <option [value]="0">Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.id"> 
        {{car.name}}
    </option>
</select>


onSelect(id) {
  console.log(`car id: `, id);
  console.log(`car`, id ? this.cars.find(c => c.id == id): "None")
}
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5uinkm

Comment: thanks, but when I use change it doesn't work at all :(

Comment: thanks.
In my case I had to use (change)="onSelect($event);" and get the value in the function onSelect with "...=event.target.value".